# Why Ubuntu Server installer doesn't provide USB disk as an installation target?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server to a USB SSD drive, but the installer only shows me the internal hard disks. I've checked on another try and have confirmed that the SSD is present and can even be mounted.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 from a bootable flash drive.

Comment: Is the computer booted in UEFI mode or the old BIOS mode? If UEFI mode, is secure boot enabled?

Comment: Since I fixed the issue in another way (installed in VirtualBox, copied the disk), I do not have physical access to the machine at the moment. However, how can UEFI or secure boot affect the fact that the installer doesn't show a disk that is clearly present on the machine, and detected by Linux? I'm thinking this should either be a bug or deliberate limitation.

Comment: You are right, it is a bug or a deliberate limitation. But I asked because of possible workarounds. One workaround is to unplug, disconnect or disable the internal drive. That will often make the installer see the external drive as `/dev/sda` and be happy to install the operating system and also the bootloading system (also in UEFI mode) into the external drive. But if you are happy with your server in VirtualBox, fine :-) You can write an answer and accept it to show other people with the same or similar problem how you solved it.

Comment: My server isn't in VirtualBox anymore. I did the installation in VirtualBox and then copied the disk to the USB disk, connected it to the server, and voila! It worked. Still a workaround, but it worked fine in the end.

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround. It worked for you, and you can write an answer and accept it to show other people with the same or similar problem how you solved it. (I think there can be problems to do so (copy/clone the system from VirtualBox) with desktop systems because of problems with the graphics driver.)